# UITableview delegate and datasource called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, tableview, datasource

I struggle with tableview datasource and delegate methods. I've a tableview if user navigate to that table view controller I'm calling web service method which is block based service after the request finished successfully reloaded tableview sections but *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath* called twice. Here's my code.

**viewDidLoad**

```
[[NetworkManager sharedInstance].webService getValues:self.currentId completion:^(NSArray *result, BOOL handleError, NSError *error) {

    self.data = result[0];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    });

}
```

but cellForRowAtIndexPath self.data value is null in the first time.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      NSLog(@"%@", self.data); // first time it print null 
}
```

So is there any ideas about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: The dataSource methods of your `UITableView` will be called after the screen is loaded as @Kex suggested, so for the first time it is `null`, and for the second time the data reloading it will be triggered from inside your async block.

Comment: try putting the reloadSections code just below self.data = result [0]; not in the dispatch block.

Comment: @Kex I was try the all way.

Comment: sorry just to be clear, does it print any value at all? It doesn't print anything on the first table call but the second call is does?

Comment: I understand now, as mentioned below it's being called twice. Initially when loaded and then in the block after the web fetch. There is nothing wrong with this code. Do you want the tableview to not initialise until you have the data or something?

Comment: @Kex Yes excally. But I workaround this like if(self.data) exists than populate delegates.

Comment: i updated my answer, try changing the number of sections code, look below

Comment: @Kex thanks dude! I solved before as metion you :) Thank you.

Comment: no problem ;)  had the same issue myself today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you initialise the data array in viewDidLoad? If you didn't it will return null.

if you want to avoid two calls to the tableview try this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(!data)
        return 0;

    return yourNumberOfSections;
}
```

Comment: sorry data isn't an array. but anyway if you didn't initialise either that or the result array it will return null.

Comment: Sorry. I know that. But it have to be filled from api.

Answer (score 1):

The tableview calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when it needs to render a cell on screen. If the tableview appears before it has any data, self.data will be empty.

In `viewDidLoad` set `[[self.data = NSMutableArray alloc] init]` (for example) and in the `datasource`/`delegate` methods of `UIITableView` it should correctly return `numberOfRows` etc as zero until your web service populates your data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called simply because the view is loaded and the table is trying to populate itself before you've received any data from your web service. At that point, you won't have set `self.data` (whatever that is) to any useful value, so you get `null` instead. When your web service returns some data, the completion routine causes the relevant sections to be reloaded, and the table draws the data.